# Error installing ns83820 driver in linux 3.2.0 (invalid physical address)

Tags: drivers

In [Debian Wheezy](http://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy) I am getting the following error on loading the `ns83820` module.

Anyone have a idea how to fix this?

```
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566727] ns83820.c: National Semiconductor DP83820 10/100/1000 driver.
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566836] ioremap: invalid physical address fffffffff4000000
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566840] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566858] WARNING: at /build/linux-dJLVDt/linux-3.2.46/arch/x86/mm/ioremap.c:83 __ioremap_caller+0xa9/0x372()
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566863] Hardware name: Unknown
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566866] Modules linked in: ns83820(+)
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566874] Pid: 73, comm: modprobe Not tainted 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 Debian 3.2.46-1
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566878] Call Trace:
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566896]  [] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x68/0x79
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566902]  [] ? __ioremap_caller+0xa9/0x372
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566907]  [] ? warn_slowpath_null+0xd/0x10
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566912]  [] ? __ioremap_caller+0xa9/0x372
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566918]  [] ? ioremap_nocache+0xa/0xd
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566927]  [] ? ns83820_init_one+0x12b/0x5d4 [ns83820]
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566935]  [] ? ns83820_init_one+0x12b/0x5d4 [ns83820]
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566944]  [] ? pci_device_probe+0x53/0x9a
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566954]  [] ? driver_probe_device+0x10c/0x10c
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566959]  [] ? driver_probe_device+0x8c/0x10c
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566964]  [] ? __driver_attach+0x40/0x5b
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566970]  [] ? bus_for_each_dev+0x3b/0x5d
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566976]  [] ? driver_attach+0x14/0x17
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566981]  [] ? driver_probe_device+0x10c/0x10c
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566985]  [] ? bus_add_driver+0x86/0x1af
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.566997]  [] ? kset_find_obj_hinted+0x4c/0x8d
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567001]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567005]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567010]  [] ? driver_register+0x73/0xc6
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567014]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567017]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567021]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567026]  [] ? __pci_register_driver+0x32/0x86
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567030]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567033]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567039]  [] ? do_one_initcall+0x66/0x10e
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567043]  [] ? 0xf8253fff
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567057]  [] ? sys_init_module+0x14c0/0x1677
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567068]  [] ? syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567072] ---[ end trace c623892f829e745a ]---
Oct  6 13:15:00 soter kernel: [    1.567118] ns83820: probe of 0000:00:08.0 failed with error -12
```

Some details:

```
$ uname --all
Linux bob 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please do not cross post: http://superuser.com/questions/658000/error-installing-ns83820-driver-in-linux-3-2-0-invalid-physical-address

Comment: Would someone be so kind as to explain how this is off topic?

Comment: Read the message below, it's pretty self explanatory, you cross posted this Q on multiple SE sites.

Comment: Cross posting is not off topic.  I was off topic in Superuser and that is why I deleted that post.  Also it is my understanding that cross posting is discouraged but not forbidden.  So I ask again is this off topic, or have you just decided that you should be the protector of Superuser.  As the one time maintainer of the NFS code in Linux I thought I might have some comments of use in this forum, but it seems that I am not wanted.

Comment: I'm by no means a "protector" so please don't insinuate anything beyond, you cross posted your Q and I saw it while trying to search for a solution and found it. The process is to vote for Q's that present like this as on hold until the situation get's worked out. We can now vote to reopen this since the nature of the Q is on topic for this site, and you've deleted the cross post.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you meant it or not, but the tone of your comment is coming across in a negative light. Since you were the maintainer of NFS in the past I would assume that you'd understand that taking that tone with ppl you're asking to help you is probably not the best approach to take.

Comment: gam4, cross posting is now one of the specific close reasons across all sites, it has been for a few months. It is not specific to U&L and certainly not specific to @slm. That's why both of your questions were closed. In fact, this question is perfectly on topic here and also on topic on superuser, you just need to chose one of the sites and stick to it. You are very welcome here and I hope you stick around. Since you have deleted the SU question, I am voting to re-open this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused buy code in the 686 *pae* code.  It does a check to make sure that the address (in this case 0xfffffffff4000000) is in range for the the number of virtual bits.  But the test fails for this address.  To solve this problem I compiled a non-pae 686 kernel and the drives then installed.